# C# or F# for Parsing Slim-like indentation-conscious languages?

Tags: c#, parsing, f#, slim-lang, recursive-descent

In order to build a parser for [Slim](http://www.slim-lang.com/)-like template languages (for ASP) in .NET, which language is more suitable C# or F#? (to me, [F#](https://github.com/fsharp/) seems more *scientific* and appropriate for such tasks..)

Other than language selection, which of the two techniques are suitable for parsing languages, in which there is 2-space incrementing indentation to describe nesting/block (such as; Slim, Haml or SCSS): **Recursive Descent Parsing** or **Recursive Ascent Parsing**?

OAN, is there any OOTB support for RDP or RAP in .NET? Or a generic, elegant third-party parsing library like Java's [parboiled](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled/wiki)?

Comment: `OAN, is there any OOTB support for RDP or RAP in .NET?`  That is funny :)

Comment: [RDP code example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19836/Palantir-Remote-Desktop-Manager)

Comment: Vote to close--extremely broad question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

F# is an excellent tool for writing parsers. You have a variety of choices:

- **Active patterns** let you define fairly simple parsers that are very readable. I used this approach in my [Markdown parser](https://github.com/tpetricek/FSharp.Formatting) I wrote a chapter about this for [an upcoming F# book](http://manning.com/petricek2/) which is freely available [as PDF](http://manning.com/petricek2/F_DeepDives_MEAP_ch3.pdf).
- **Parser combinators** are another options. The idea is that you can build parser from basic building blocks (such as parsing a list separated by a given character etc.). There is an F# implementation called [FParsec](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/)
- **FsLex and FsYacc** give you the standard tools for writing parsers. There is [a new more efficient implementation](https://github.com/jack-pappas/fsharp-tools) and also a version in the [F# PowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/) which is used by the F# compiler itself.

Answer (score 3):

F# is an indentation-sensitive language itself and F# compiler uses `fslex/fsyacc` for parsing. If you take a look at [F#'s parser](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/pars.fsy), indentation sensitiveness adds extra complexities to this process.

If you don't have much experience with F#, hand-rolled F# parser is probably not a good idea. I would recommend to use [FParsec](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/). It has the flexibility of hand-rolled parsers and is much simpler to use than `fslex/fsyacc`.

You can find two implementations of an indentation-based grammar in FParsec from [this article](https://bitbucket.org/fparsec/main/wiki/Parsing%20indentation-based%20syntax%20with%20FParsec).

Answer (score 1):

To build a homebrew parser in C#.NET, you may want to look into [Rxx](http://rxx.codeplex.com/) extension for Microsoft Reactive Extension (Rx).

Also, checkout this list for creating. [parsers in C#](http://cascadeofinsights.com/post/1629270971/parser-combinators-in-c).